# What is the recommended way to store an NSArray on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, core-data, nsarray, nsdictionary, nsuserdefaults

I've been looking around for a way to store an `NSArray` containing lots of `NSDictionaries`. So far I've come across a few different ways of doing it, the most popular of these seems to be the `NSUserDefaults` approach. That said, it just doesn't seem right to me. In my mind the NSUserDefaults should only really be used for storing the settings a user has selected.

Please can someone help me out with the best way to approach this problem? I'm certain that there must be some standard approach, however I can't seem to pin it down!

Comment: plist are also one way to go if your data is not more than 1-2MB and `if you are not using it across your application`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple does has a framework that provides [generalized and automated solutions to common tasks associated with object life-cycle and object graph management, including persistence](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/coredata/cdprogrammingguide.html). ;-)

Seriously though, Core Data should be your first port of call, since it is optimised for the platform, and will scale too. Once you get your head around how it works, it's really fairly straightforward. Also, it's likely to perform better than any roll-your-own solution you come up with.

Comment: I should add that my answer was based on my interpretation of "lots of `NSDictionaries`". A plist is indeed the most suitable, as @robin has commented, for smaller data volumes.

Comment: I think that the plist option is the path I will follow. Thank you for your advice!

Comment: Probably fair to mark @Caleb's answer as the correct one then!

Answer (score 1):

Please read [*Archives and Serializations Programming Guide*](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Archiving/Archiving.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000047-SW1). The top two choices will be to save the array as a property list, or to create an archive using NSKeyedArchiver.