# iOS - Saving NSMutableArray to iPhone

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray, save

I'll ask in the form of a hypothetical, which might make it easier for me to explain.

I have a class called `Person`, and in this has three fields:

- `NSString *name`;
- `NSDate *dateOfBirth`; and
- `NSMutableArray *friends`.

An example object is this:

- `name` = "John Smith"
- `dateOfBirth` = 01/04/1985
- `friends` = "Simon Scott"; "Jennifer Lane"; "Mary Firth"

Once the user has filled the `NSMutableArray` with the data they want, what would be the best way to save this data to the iPhone? I would anticipate that there could be up to 100 instances of the `Person` object, and all that will be required is the displaying of this data in a `UITableView` and giving the user the ability to add and remove entries at their will.

I have seen multiple suggestions on this site, which include NSDictionaries and using the writeToFile method, but before I research one of these, I was hoping someone could point me in the right direction? I would like to ensure that I'll be using the easiest and most appropriate method that's out there.

Many thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the recommended way to store an NSArray on iPhone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8574924/what-is-the-recommended-way-to-store-an-nsarray-on-iphone)

Comment: "...but before I research one of these..." Your first research should be to look for related questions on SO, and also to read [relevant](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Archiving/Archiving.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000047-SW1) [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000048-CJBGDEGD).

Answer (score 2):

Please take a look at the [Property List Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000048-CJBGDEGD). As long as you stick with a core set of object types for your data, you can write and read your data from a file or URL in one line, like this:

```
[people writeToURL:someURL atomically:NO];
```

The types you've mentioned in your question (strings, dates, arrays, dictionaries) can all be written to a property list.

Comment: I would say `writeToFile` is more preferred.

Answer (score 0):

@Achiral,

It really depends on what you want to do with the data and how concerned you are with the flexibility of your code.

However, my recommendation would be to use CoreData to make an SQLlite database and make a 'Person' entity with the properties that you list above. I don't know if you are familiar with CoreData, but it is highly optimized on iOS and is pretty easy to use, since it has a pretty simple 'fill in the blanks' style form for creating the data models. You should also note that CoreData is a well accepted and supported way to store data in an iOS and OS X app.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Note that Core Data is generally considered an advanced topic. If you're just starting out, you'd be better off with a property list or an archive.

Comment: @Caleb, I do agree that it is more advanced than say writing to a plist or something similar, but it really isn't all that hard and there are a number of CoreData resources for beginners online these days; also, a good way to stunt one's growth as a Cocoa / Cocoa Touch developer is to fear CoreData. :)

Comment: There's a difference between fear and KISS (i.e. Keep It Simple Stupid). The very first document one should read on Core Data says in part: [Core Data is not an entry-level technology.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/GettingStartedWithCoreData/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005316-CH1-SW3) There's just a lot of other stuff that you need to know first. By contrast, `[people writeToURL:someURL atomically:NO];` is dead simple and probably all the OP needs at this point. Why get bogged down in over-engineering when you can have fun writing your app?

Comment: @Caleb Though I have to agree to that CoreData is 'harder', it is hardly over engineering when you consider the possibility of changing business requirements and the like; please note that I have made the assumption that the asker is either doing a contract or is doing this for some other kind of assignment.  However, if he is not doing this in an arena in which other people might see it or he'd go through a code review, then yeah do the whatever you want; I am actually not being snide here but I myself have gone through a brutal code review for not using CD and writing to a plist...